# Memory problem when viewing PDFDocument Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, pdfkit

I have PDF document with 58mb size and 1000 numbers of page.

I'm viewing this document with PDFKit&
But when I search text & viewing this document I have problem with memory.

[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsjKn.png)

[Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vjrt.png)

Can anyone help me free up memory after page viewing?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you keep seeing this same high memory usage after the page is dismissed? Or is it just while the page is viewed?

Comment: @ArikSegal created test project with 1 controller. but if I force make pdfDocument = nil, still the memory is not freed

for example I make 
```self.pdfDocument?.findString("text", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)```
and memory 500mb
after I make 
```self.pdfDocumen = nil```
and memory also 500mb

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest trying one of the following modifications:

1. Use the following Asynchronous method:
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436078-beginfindstring

or

2. Make sure you perform the findString operation in a background thread

Comment: the problem is not with threads.
the problem is that seek (on any thread) does not release memory.

How to release memory? autorelease is not help